# A NullPointerException is caught when I try to add a new client in a CRUD Spring boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am doing a CRUD web application using Spring boot, spring mvc and Spring Data JPA. I wanted to test my code in the main class with adding a new client. It returns me a NullPointerException. I already check my code with a debug mode. Honestly I don't see where is exactly the issue, so, if it's possible to help it will be a pleasure.

**Entity class :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cliente")
public class Cliente implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer idCliente;
    private String iceCliente;
    private String nombreCliente;
    private String apellidoCliente;
    private String direccionCliente;
    private String telefonoCliente;
    private String emailCliente;
    private TipoCliente tipoCliente;
    private String cuidadCliente;

    public Cliente() {
        super();
    }

    public Cliente(String iceCliente, String nombreCliente, String apellidoCliente, String direccionCliente,
            String telefonoCliente, String emailCliente, TipoCliente tipoCliente, String cuidadCliente) {
        super();
        this.iceCliente = iceCliente;
        this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
        this.apellidoCliente = apellidoCliente;
        this.direccionCliente = direccionCliente;
        this.telefonoCliente = telefonoCliente;
        this.emailCliente = emailCliente;
        this.tipoCliente = tipoCliente;
        this.cuidadCliente = cuidadCliente;
    }

    public Integer getIdCliente() {
        return idCliente;
    }

    public void setIdCliente(int idCliente) {
        this.idCliente = idCliente;
    }

    public String getIceCliente() {
        return iceCliente;
    }

    public void setIceCliente(String iceCliente) {
        this.iceCliente = iceCliente;
    }

    public String getNombreCliente() {
        return nombreCliente;
    }

    public void setNombreCliente(String nombreCliente) {
        this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
    }

    public String getApellidoCliente() {
        return apellidoCliente;
    }

    public void setApellidoCliente(String apellidoCliente) {
        this.apellidoCliente = apellidoCliente;
    }

    public String getDireccionCliente() {
        return direccionCliente;
    }

    public void setDireccionCliente(String direccionCliente) {
        this.direccionCliente = direccionCliente;
    }

    public String getTelefonoCliente() {
        return telefonoCliente;
    }

    public void setTelefonoCliente(String telefonoCliente) {
        this.telefonoCliente = telefonoCliente;
    }

    public String getEmailCliente() {
        return emailCliente;
    }

    public void setEmailCliente(String emailCliente) {
        this.emailCliente = emailCliente;
    }

    public TipoCliente getTipoCliente() {
        return tipoCliente;
    }

    public void setTipoCliente(TipoCliente tipoCliente) {
        this.tipoCliente = tipoCliente;
    }

    public String getCuidadCliente() {
        return cuidadCliente;
    }

    public void setCuidadCliente(String cuidadCliente) {
        this.cuidadCliente = cuidadCliente;
    }
```

**ClienteService :**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ClienteServiceImpl implements ClienteService {

    @Autowired
    ClienteRepository clienteRepository;

    @Override
    public Cliente agregarCliente(Cliente cliente) {

        return clienteRepository.save(cliente);
    }

    @Override
    public Cliente editarCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        Optional<Cliente> clienteDB = this.clienteRepository.findById(cliente.getIdCliente());
        if (clienteDB.isPresent()) {
            Cliente clienteUpdate = clienteDB.get();
            clienteUpdate.setIdCliente(cliente.getIdCliente());
            clienteUpdate.setIceCliente(cliente.getIceCliente());
            clienteUpdate.setNombreCliente(cliente.getNombreCliente());
            clienteUpdate.setApellidoCliente(cliente.getApellidoCliente());
            clienteUpdate.setDireccionCliente(cliente.getDireccionCliente());
            clienteUpdate.setCuidadCliente(cliente.getCuidadCliente());
            clienteUpdate.setTelefonoCliente(cliente.getTelefonoCliente());
            clienteUpdate.setEmailCliente(cliente.getEmailCliente());
            clienteRepository.save(clienteUpdate);
            return clienteUpdate;
        } else {
            throw new RessourceNotFoundException(
                    "Cliente no encontrado con nombre de usuario : " + cliente.getIdCliente());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public List<Cliente> obtenerCliente() {

        return this.clienteRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeCliente(Integer idCliente) {

        Optional<Cliente> clienteDB = this.clienteRepository.findById(idCliente);

        if (clienteDB.isPresent()) {
            this.clienteRepository.delete(clienteDB.get());
        } else {
            throw new RessourceNotFoundException("Cliente no encontrado con nombre de usuario : " + idCliente);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Cliente obtenerClientePorId(Integer idCliente) {

        Optional<Cliente> clienteDB = this.clienteRepository.findById(idCliente);

        if (clienteDB.isPresent()) {
            return clienteDB.get();
        } else {
            throw new RessourceNotFoundException("Cliente no encontrado con nombre de usuario : " + idCliente);
        }

    }
```

**ClienteRepository :**

```
@Repository
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Integer> {

}
```

**ClienteController :**

```
@RestController
//@RequestMapping("/index")
public class ClienteController {

    @Autowired
    private ClienteService clienteService;

    @GetMapping("/clientes")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Cliente>> obtenerCliente() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(clienteService.obtenerCliente());
    }

    @GetMapping("/clientes/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Cliente> obtenerClientePorId(@PathVariable Integer idCliente) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(clienteService.obtenerClientePorId(idCliente));
    }

    @PostMapping("/clientes")
    public ResponseEntity<Cliente> agregarCliente(@RequestBody Cliente cliente) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(this.clienteService.agregarCliente(cliente));
    }

    @PutMapping("/clientes/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Cliente> editarCliente(@PathVariable Integer idCliente, @RequestBody Cliente cliente) {
        cliente.setIdCliente(idCliente);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(this.clienteService.editarCliente(cliente));
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/clientes/{id}")
    public HttpStatus removeCliente(@PathVariable Integer idCliente) {
        this.clienteService.removeCliente(idCliente);
        return HttpStatus.OK;
    }
```

**Main class :**

```
@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class NestideasFacturasApplication {

    @Autowired
    public static ClienteService clienteService = new ClienteServiceImpl();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NestideasFacturasApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Application démarrée");



        System.out.println(clienteService);

        clienteService.agregarCliente(new Cliente("16565465", "Hassan", "JROUNDI", "Said Hajji", "0662165537",
                "hassan.jroundi@outlook.fr", TipoCliente.EMPREZA, "Salé"));

        System.out.println(clienteService);

    }
```

Stacktrace :

[Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4iFm.png)

Comment: Don't inject them to the `NestideasFacturasApplication` class. Create a different one, fairly sure this is too early in `lifecycle` for them to be injected.

Comment: This is wrong : `@Autowired public static ClienteService clienteService = new ClienteServiceImpl();`  out side application context. if you want to this works then you should get `ApplicationContext` asks for a bean called `CliendServiceImpl` then use it....

Comment: Just tested it, same exception. Thank you for your fast reply.

Comment: I doubt you can inject beans inside boot starter main class because this is very early in the application context lifecycle. Consider using moving logic in main to ApplicationListener and inject ClienteService instead of creating manually.

Comment: Excuse me guys, I am not very powerful with Java EE and their frameworks. I am actually on a training and to be honest some of terms are foreign for me. If it's possible for you guys to explain more your advices I will reconnaissant. Thank you !

Comment: I can help you ping me to this email `johxgks@gmail.com`. I will remove this message when you do it.

Comment: share the stacktrace

Comment: [link]https://zupimages.net/up/20/04/zhir.png[/link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **First**, for your test scenario, it's better to use `ApplicationRunner`.

`NestideasFacturasApplication` must implement `ApplicationRunner`, and override `run` method. Then you can write your test scenario in `run`.

**Code** :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class NestideasFacturasApplication  implements ApplicationRunner {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(NestideasFacturasApplication.class, args);

    }


    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {

      //Your test scenario ...          

    }
}
```

> **Second**, Change injection of ClienteService like below

```
@Autowired
private ClienteService clienteService;
```

> **So we have (Entire code)**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class NestideasFacturasApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ClienteService clienteService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NestideasFacturasApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {

        //Your test scenario
        System.out.println("Application démarrée");
        System.out.println(clienteService);

        clienteService.agregarCliente(new Cliente("16565465", "Hassan", "JROUNDI", "Said Hajji", "0662165537", "hassan.jroundi@outlook.fr", TipoCliente.EMPREZA, "Salé"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh ! you just save my night. I can finally go through front part of the project. Thank you so much for you help I appreciate it.